# Python code isnt producing output, please advice on why

Tags: python

I have an assignment to write code to print a number in words. I'm new to coding, so please do not judge my code... . so ive written the code am fairly certain it should work, but it isnt producing an output. there's no syntax error apparently either. Please advice. If theres a better code please let me know as well but i would like to know why my code doesnt work

This is the code:

```
x=0
Dictcom= {1:'One ',2:'Two ',3:'Three ',4:'Four ',5:'Five ',6:'Six ',7:'Seven ',8:'Eight ',9:'Nine '}
Placename={2:'Hundred ',3:'Thousand ',5:'Hundred ',6:'Million ',8:'Hundred ',9:'Billion '}
Ortyplanename={2:'Twenty ',3:'Thirty ',4:'Forty ',5:'Fifty ',6:'Sixty ',7:'Seventy ',8:'Eighty ',9:'Ninety '}
OnesTensCase={10:'Ten ',11:'Eleven ',12:'Twelve ',13:'Thirteen ',14:'Fourteen ',15:'Fifteen ',16:'Sixteen ',17:'Seventeen '
,18:'Eighteen ',19:'Nineteen '}
n=input("Enter a number less than 11 digits: ")
x=y=0
S=''
for i in n:
    x+=1
n=int(n)
while x>(-1):
    y=n//10**(x-1)
    if y==0:
        continue
    elif x==2 or x==5 or x==8:                                     
        n=str(n)
        if n[0:2] in OnesTensCase:
            S+=OnesTensCase[n[0:2]]
        elif y in Ortyplanename:
            S+=Ortyplanename[y]
    else:
        if y!=0:
            str(y)
            S+=Dictcom[y]
        if (x-1) in Placename:
                S+=Placename[x-1]
                if x!=0:
                    S+="And "
    n=int(n)
    n=n%10**(x-1)
    x-=1
print(S)
```

Comment: You can really easily debug stuff like this yourself with a debugger. If you aren't using one, you need to learn how; it's something you should have learned the very first day you started learning programming. PyCharm is a free IDE with an excellent debugger. Here is how you use it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: i used the vs code debugger, it says it doesnt have any problems

Comment: Then you have no idea what a debugger is for. It's not just a magical tool that tells you your code works or not. It allows you to step through each line of code, following along, and seeing exactly what each line of code does, what variables change, how the control flow changes, etc. It lets you actually see what's happening under the hood. It's an absolutely necessary tool for any developer. It sounds like you should stop what you're doing and learn how to do line-by-line debugging ASAP. Otherwise that's like trying to learn to paint without looking at the canvas until you think you're done.

Comment: No problem. Also, that's just my suggestion; don't feel like you have to do it because I said so. That's just my recommendation to you, as a software engineer who works in industry. If I were to interview a candidate who said they didn't know how to debug, or even knew exactly what that was, I would not even consider hiring them. The more experience you can get using one, and the more comfortable you are with debuggers, the better.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the infinite loop that is preventing your output from displaying, is that on the very last loop iteration, the following line will set `y` to `0`:

```
y=n//10**(x-1)
```

And since right after that you have the following:

```
if y==0:
    continue
```

That means your code will infinitely loop on the last loop iteration. This is because on the last loop iteration, the value of `x` is `0`, and the value of `n` is `0`, and so `0//10**(0-1)` will obviously equal zero.

Otherwise though your code works okay. I put in the number `123456789` and the text representation was accurate except there were too many `"And"`s, but I know that's unrelated to your question:

`One Hundred And Twenty Three Million And Four Hundred And Fifty Six Thousand And Seven Hundred And Eighty Nine`